Optimization Methods for Reducing AAOS Boot Time
I am trying to reduce the boot time of Android Automotive OS (AAOS) beyond the methods provided in the official optimization guidelines. I am looking for practical tips and real-world techniques from experienced developers who have found effective solutions.
I am seeking additional optimization methods beyond those mentioned in the official AAOS documentation, in order to achieve better performance.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
